# macOS - os.listdir returns double items which starts with "."?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os, exfat

Despite that the folder has **two** files (`a.apk`, and `b.apk`), `os.listdir` function returns **four** files such as `._b.apk`, `._a.apk`, `a.apk`, and `b.apk`. Where do the first two files come from? How can I prevent Python to list them?

Software Stack:

```
- OS: macOS Catalina
- Python: 3.7.3
```

p.s. The files are stored in an external flash drive, which is formatted as `ExFAT`.

Comment: BTW, "Despite that the folder has **two** files (`a.apk`, and `b.apk`)": who says that? Obviously, it isn't the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do the first two files come from?

For this part, see this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them

> How can I prevent Python to list them?

Neither [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) nor  [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) nor [*`os.path.walk()`*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk) *(only in Python 2)* have a parameter immediately suppressing this kind of files, as for the underlying OS, these are normal files. It's the UI which makes this distinction.

So you'll have to do it on your own:

```
files = [i for i in os.listdir(".") if not i.startswith("._")]
```

would be one option.

If you want to suppress all hidden files (i. e., all files which start with a `.`), do

```
files = [i for i in os.listdir(".") if not i.startswith(".")]
```

instead.

Comment: Yes, I have already eliminated these files through the same way you mentioned. Actually I asked if there is a parameter for that.